# How to avoid sending third-party requests to my serverless function on vercel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vercel

I have a game made in React and JS, and a server running serverless on Vercel.

When you authenticate to my game (for now, all you need is a username), the server checks if the user already exists, and if not, creates a new one. Then it creates a JWT token that it sends back to the frontend thanks to an httpOnly cookie.

When you play my game, you get a score, which is sent after the game to the DB via a POST request to /api/(my function). In the body of the request, I return the score and the name, and in the header I return the cookie we received earlier when we connected.

My problem is that when a user logs in and then retrieves the token in the header of the browser console, he can then go to postman and make a POST request to mondomaine/api/(ma fonction) and thus add a score that he didn't obtain while playing.

I've looked everywhere on the Internet and I can't find a way to avoid this.

Maybe I need to rethink my connection logic? If you have any ideas, I'd love to hear from you.

Comment: have you maybe tried to set the apropriate Allowed-Origin in he headers?

Comment: I tried but it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything done on client side can be forged, there's no way to prevent that.

All you can do is make it harder to cheat, and try to detect cheaters.

The most secure design is to have the server track the game state, while the client only sends user actions. If the user action is valid, the server updates game state (like score) and tells the frontend what the new state is. But, this can introduce latency and users can still use bots that send valid actions.

Another strategy is to track the history of the game's state on the frontend, and send that to the backend for validation. Only accept their score if the game they played was valid and actually lead to that score. Someone can still forge a valid game history, but it's more difficult than just sending a high score.

More reading:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113281/prevent-cheating-in-html-javascript-game

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37392/anti-cheat-javascript-for-browser-html5-game

---

You can always just let people cheat too, especially if it's a single player game.